# Visual Studio + Search Server Express 2010 startup issues

Tags: search, visual-studio-2015

I have a project to search through about 100,000 Office docs, html files, and pdf's from an ASP.NET web forms interface, and present a curated set of results to the end-user for further action. My last contact with search was with Search indexer on Windows Server 2003. The current platform is WS2012 at a customer site. My budget doesn't allow for anything other than free (thus the express), or perhaps jumping ship to a third party crawler/indexer solution under $1K.

I have a big picture question: Is Search Server Express 2010 a good solution here?

If so, I have been banging my head for three days trying to get past the return error:

"System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation. at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall) at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters) at...."

when hitting the search.aspx from a development machine. I've been able to iterate through various settings, and anything other than anonymous enabled for search.asmx causes a 401 error. I'm using a hopefully standard query from Microsoft. Thanks in advance for any guidance.

```
    private string GetXMLString()
    {
        StringBuilder xmlString = new StringBuilder("<QueryPacket xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search.Query'><Query><SupportedFormats><Format revision='1'>urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document:Document</Format></SupportedFormats><Context><QueryText language='en-US' type='STRING'>");
        xmlString.Append(this.queryTextBox.Text);
        xmlString.Append("</QueryText></Context></Query></QueryPacket>");
        return xmlString.ToString();
    }

  protected void queryButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //per MS document:
            // Instantiate the Web service.
            QueryWebServiceProxy.QueryService queryService = new QueryWebServiceProxy.QueryService();
            // Use the credentials of the user running the client application. 

            //I have also tried
            // queryService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            //to this:
            System.Net.NetworkCredential _credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("theUser", "thePassword", "theDomain");
            queryService.Credentials = _credentials;
            queryService.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            queryService.PreAuthenticate = true;

            //Execute the QueryEx method, returning the results to a DataSet
            System.Data.DataSet queryResults = queryService.QueryEx(GetXMLString());
            // Set the DataGridView data source to the first table in the DataSet oject, which contains the relevant results.
            resultsGrid.DataSource = queryResults.Tables[0];

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            resultsLabel.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```